# Basic File Won't Run -> Unable to initialize device PRN

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am very new to Python, and have recently switched to VS Code from Jupyter Notebooks, and am trying to run some simple code but am getting an error.

I've looked around for the solution already, and I can find the same error message but nothing matches my issue.

I'm just doing very basic code:

```
msg = 'Hello World'
print('msg')
```

The error message I get is in the terminal and looks like this:

```
(base) C:\Projects\Python\Tutorial>print(msg)
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

Comment: You need to be in a Python environment to run that code or you need to invoke the Python interpreter.  You're still in the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rayryeng said you need to run your code in a Python environment.

If you are using VS code there is Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) where you can run your code interactively. To activate it you can press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type/find `Python: Start REPL` after that you will see terminal panel at the bottom of VS Code as on screenshot:[image: VS Code running Python shell]

Sure, you need VS Code Python extension and Python itself installed in your system.

Alternatively you can run Python shell directly from your command line by typing `python` or `python2`/`python3` depending on your installed version. Python must be in the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))